# Problem in understanding different combinations of const and Iterable in Dart

Tags: dart

I am new to Dart, and I've been experimenting with the Iterable datatype. In the course of learning, I came across different ways of declaring and initializing Iterable variables. Here's what I've tried:

```
void main () {
 Iterable<String> iterable = ['Salad', 'Popcorn', 'Toast'];
 Iterable<String> iterable2 = const ['Salad', 'Popcorn', 'Toast'];
 const Iterable<String> iterable3 = ['Salad', 'Popcorn', 'Toast'];

 var iterable4 = ['Salad', 'Popcorn', 'Toast'];
 var iterable5 = const ['Salad', 'Popcorn', 'Toast'];
 const iterable6 = ['Salad', 'Popcorn', 'Toast'];
}
```

I am a bit confused about the differences between these six declarations. Could someone explain the nuances regarding how they're declared and what's possible or not to do with them? For example, can I add or remove elements from these Iterables, or are there restrictions on some of them?

Thank you for your assistance.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a `const` list literal by adding the `const` keyword before the opening bracket, as you have done in examples 2 and 5.

You can also create a `const` list by declaring a `const` variable, as the value of such a variable must be `const`. You have done this in examples 3 and 6.

A `const` list can never be changed at runtime. The difference between these two types of declarations is that the variables declared in the first fashion (regular variables) can be *reassigned*. While you can't, for example, add an item to the lists, you can assign new lists to those variables. You cannot do this with the `const` variables.

As for the difference between the first and last three variables, you are upcasting the first three from `List` to `Iterable`. This means that you cannot use any `List` APIs such as `add`. Type inference takes place in the last three declarations, so they are implicitly `List` variables.